# Is there currently a way to use HTML5 <meta> tags outside of <head> in WebKit?

Tags: html, google-chrome, webkit, microdata

I'm trying to use `<meta>` tags throughout my HTML document to mark-up hidden microdata values, as descriped in Mark Pilgrim's [Dive Into HTML 5](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/extensibility.html). However, when my page loads in Chrome (specifically, Chromium 6.0.418.0), I get the following error messages:

```
<meta> is not allowed inside <article>. Moving <meta> into the <head>.
<meta> is not allowed inside <span>. Moving <meta> into the <head>.
<meta> is not allowed inside <div>. Moving <meta> into the <head>.
```

Is there currently a workaround for this? The same thing happens in Firefox 3.6.13, though I am particularly interested in a workaround for WebKit at this time.

Comment: Do you have a correct HTML5 doctype? Edit: just looking at it again, maybe this was one of the things taken out of HTML5 at one point?

Comment: I do have a correct HTML5 doctype. I suppose it's possible that this was taken out of HTML5, but as far as I know it is still in the specification. I guess it just doesn't have browser support yet.

Comment: Seems like microdata got pushed out of the main HTML5 spec and relegated to its own document, marked as "controversial": http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/microdata.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

More recent versions of WebKit have, like Firefox, an HTML5-compliant parser, and support `meta` elements outside the `head` element.

I should also note that W3Schools is not related to the W3C, and is well known to publish utter nonsense. Also, Microdata is still part of HTML, and using it is perfectly fine. The fact that it is published in a separate draft at the W3C does not change that in any way.

Comment: It doesn't appear to valid in W3C HTML5 though. I can't find any equivalent of the WHATWG "If the itemprop attribute is present: where phrasing content is expected." line for "Contexts in which this element [meta] can be used"

Comment: I tried this in the lastest versions and it looks like it works in Chrome but not in Firefox (on Mac OS X). Even though I was originally looking for workarounds, I'm accepting this answer since it is actually supported in WebKit.

Comment: To beef up the "W3C Schools is nonsense" claim, I recommend using [Chrome's Personal Blocklist plugin/extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nolijncfnkgaikbjbdaogikpmpbdcdef) to hide all http://w3schools.com/ from your Google results. Also, just prepend [MDC](http://developer.mozilla.org/) to every web-development question your Googling about. It'll usually get you the correct info you need.

Comment: @CpnCrunch: sorry to hear that, sadly my comment is accurate.

Comment: Ms2ger: first of all, there is no mention of w3fools in the question (unless it was edited out), so I'm not sure why you added it. Secondly, w3schools is fine for the most part. I usually use it to look up things quickly. Even w3fools now acknowledges that most of the errors have been fixed. However, having said that, I had a look at the info on the meta tag on w3schools and I see that it says it is only permitted in the head element. I'd suggest you update the answer to explain why w3schools is wrong in this case. I tried to upvote you but SO won't let me until the answer is edited :)

Comment: @OryBand I'm sure you meant prepend the search with MDN

Answer (score 11):

Both the HTML Microdata spec (Editor's Draft from 8 July 2011) and the schema.org <del>spec</del> vocabulary by Google, Microsoft, and Yahoo allowed the `meta` element to be placed into the body as part of semantic data in the microdata format.

- http://dev.w3.org/html5/md/#the-basic-syntax
- http://schema.org/docs/gs.html#advanced_missing

As of July 2011, IE 9, FF 5, and Chrome 12 do not throw this error; Safari 5 still does.  (Tested on Win 7)  More importantly (IMHO) the W3C's validator does not throw an error.

Here is a valid example of the `meta` element in the body:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Testing Meta in the Body</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div itemscope>
            <meta itemprop="name" content="HTML5 Logo">
            <figure>
                <img src="html5.png">
                <figcaption>The HTML5 Logo</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```